# Which is better, img or background-image, for page content load times?

Tags: css, background-image

I am making a tumblr theme which will have a pretty large image in the background (approx. 2000x1600px). However I need the page's content, the tumblr posts, to load relatively quickly. Which of these options would be faster?

```
<style>
    body {background-image: "background.png"}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        /* tumblr posts go here */
    </div>
</body>
```

or

```
<style>
    img {z-index: 0}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        /* tumblr posts go here */
    </div>
    <img src="background.png">
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself yet?

Comment: The browser will have to download the image just the same, no matter how you place it.

Comment: @TylerH No, I have no idea how to make a tumblr theme and I'm currently looking at a blank page.

Comment: @Juhana The second example loads the image after the content, while I'm not completely sure what order the first example loads in.

Comment: No, it *places* the image after the content. The browser loads the images asynchronously.

Comment: @Herossaumure I meant creating a demo in JSFiddle or a similar tool with the two implementations and timing how long each page takes to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two don't really differ from one another.

If you open up Chrome Dev Tools and take a look in the Network Tab, the load times will be the same because the size of the image remains as is.

However, what you can do here, is leverage the power of CSS along with some Javascript. Apply the background image to a class, say `.with-background`, and then with some jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('body').addClass('with-background');
});
```

This way, when everything else on the page (including other images, thus the listener on 'window.load') is loaded, apply this class, which will then load up the background image.

As a simple sidenote, if you don't want your body to remain blank while the content loads, what you can do is take that huge image, downscale it, and blur it (in Photoshop or other image editing software). That way "something resembling that image is back there" - all the while being very small in Kb. In turn, when the class is applied, you'll get your full-sized image.

Check out posts with images on medium.com - they do a similar thing. It is a design choice, more than anything else.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go see how this works out (though I have the feeling I'm in way over my head on this project).

Comment: @Herossaumure sure thing. And I just updated the original answer with a sidenote, just in case.